# Deserialization failed: Error when trying to open cube designer in Visual Studio (SSAS)

Tags: visual-studio, runtime-error, ssas, business-intelligence, cube

I just received the following error when I trying to open a cube in the designer view. This is most likely due to the fact that I was reorganizing my measure groups and there must be a duplicate measure somewhere.

How can I re-open the cube designer? I can see the DSV.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by right clicking on the .cube project and opening View Code.

[image]

I made sure that the measures had different names and saved the cube project.

```
      <Name>Measure name</Name>
```

The error message disappeared and I can finally use the cube designer again.